# Restoring window size on customized minimize button

Tags: c#

I created a custom window since forms do not allow me to change the color of its border from light blue to something else. So I just chose no border for the form and just created buttons for "Close", "Maximize", and "Minimize" all of this works except that, when I minimize the form, all of the buttons disappear and I am not able to make the form normal size anymore. Could you please tell me how to restore the form to its original size when minimized and if you have an idea on how to bring the buttons with the form as soon as it is minimized? 
I tried putting the code for windowState.Normal in the onDoubleClick event of the form but it's a no go. Thanks for the help.

CODES:

```
private void btnMaximize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized ? FormWindowState.Normal : FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }

    private void btnMinimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WindowState = WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized ? FormWindowState.Normal : FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }

   private void panel2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

         if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
         {
             WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
         }
    }

    private void Add_Student_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work `private void Add_Student_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)`
This doesn't work `private void panel2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Answer (score 0):

I am curious about how to get a double click if form is minimized.

```
private void panel2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
     {
         WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
     }
}
```

Comment: I was just trying to do something to solve the issue. Can you tell me what to do?

Comment: In your case using custom buttons, adjust the form size instead of form-window state.